# Why doesn't my use of "let" prevent the classic closure problem with setTimeout and consecutive variables?

Tags: javascript, closures

See this code:

```
for(var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    setTimeout(function() {
        console.log(i);
    }, 200);
}
```

This is the classic bug where it prints the final value of `i` repeatedly instead of printing the desired consecutive output.

I know it can be fixed like so by using `let` instead of `var`:

```
for(let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    setTimeout(function() {
        console.log(i);
    }, 200);
}
```

What confuses me is why this *doesn't* fix it:

```
for(var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    setTimeout(function() {
        let n = i;
        console.log(n);
    }, 200);
}
```

Now it should be fixed for the same reason as the previous code, but the bug persists. Why is that?

Comment: It's too late; `i` already has the wrong value.

Comment: Ohhhhhhhhhhhh. You should make that an answer.

Comment: For the same reason the first doesn't work.

Comment: If `let n = i` was outside of `setTimeout()` and inside the `for` block then it would work.

Comment: let is block scoped. var is function scoped. By the time the first timeout function is called `i` is already at 4 so it sets `n` to 4 and it logs 4 all the way down

Comment: Is there anything else I should include in my answer? Or is it sufficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a special behavior for `let` declarations in the head of a for loop. The variable is declared uniquely for every iteration. That is why example #2 "works".

In example #3, the `var i` declaration only happens once, and the value is updated each iteration. `let` is also declared at execution time. So each time the callback function in example #3 executes, the first time being after ALL the iterations of the for loop have have happened, `let n = i` is declared (at execution time) and `i` at this time is the single `i` that was declared in the for loop.

I encourage to just read through this real quick. https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/master/scope%20%26%20closures/ch5.md#block-scoping-revisited

```
console.log(a);
var a = 10;
```

will print `undefined` because at the time of `console.log` `a` was declared but not assigned.

```
console.log(a);
let (or const) a = 10;
```

will throw a `TypeError` because at the time of `console.log` `a` was not declared yet.

Answer (score 1):

You are still referencing `i` within the `setTimeout` callback function, so you still have a closure around it. It's really no different than your first example of the "classic" closure problem with timers.

The reason the `let` example avoids the issue is that, even though `i` is referenced within the timer callback, it's not the same `i` as from the earlier loop iteration. Each iteration gets its own `i`.